# cudnn can't be install

Tags: theano, theano-cuda, cudnn

I am trying the [LeNet5](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) on theano using cuda 8.0 windows 10 GTX 770M, and it seems the params cannot be updated correctedly. 
When I import theano, I will get this error:

```
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:
c:\users\yanjun~1\appdata\local\temp\try_flags_8n7fhy.c:4:19: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce GTX 770M (0000:01:00.0)
```

I have installed cudnn 5 to my cuda 8.0 by copying the files to "NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0", but still the same error shows.

Is it because theano cannot compile the cudnn， both `conv2d` and `pool_2d` cannot work properly？ As result， my error rate keeps around 90% while training. Did I install cudnn correctly? I just followed the [instructions](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.htmlhttp://) on theano's documentation, but no .so* file in the zip.

I've tried the cpu mode, it can be trained properly but really really slow.

Hope you guys could help me out of this where I am stuck for servel days.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when migrating to the new theano back-end, and fixed it with the following steps (inside my conda environment).

1. Update theano with `conda update theano` and get pygpy with `conda install -c rdonnelly pygpu`. I'm installing a RC package since it gave less issues.
2. Check if you need to make changes to your code [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29) Since I was using keras, I did not have to do so.
3. Change theanorc from `device = gpu` to `device = cuda0`. If you went to the above link, you might have already done so.
4. Add to the bottom of your theanorc file:

   ```
   compiler_bindir = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

   [cuda]
   root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0

   [dnn]
   library_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64
   include_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include
   ```